# MySQL Trigger BEFORE delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables called "Batteries" and "Runs" with the first referenced on the second one by a field called  "BatteryId". 
I have a trigger on Runs that fires after INSERT that inserts into another table called "BatteryActions" that I use to trace the charge and discharge actions on every battery record within "Batteries".

In case I need to delete a row from Runs, I need to delete also the referred row within BatteryActions so I need to create a trigger before delete on Runs but, and here comes the question, how can I get the id of the row I'm going to delete to put in into the trigger?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: You can use the keyword `OLD` within the trigger (eg.: `OLD.id`), see [20.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html). You can also use `Referential Actions`, specifically `CASCADE`, see [13.1.17.2 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to use the way of foreign keys. Do you know if there's a way to retrieve the record just inserted, updated or on the way to be deleted from within a trigger?

Comment: The `OLD` and `NEW` keywords do what you need, see [20.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html).